# Denver International Airport pneumatic tube systems

Tags: airport, usa, ground-operations

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatic_tube%23Current_use) says:

> Denver International Airport uses many pneumatic tube systems, including a 25 cm diameter system for moving aircraft parts to remote concourses, a 10 cm system for United Airlines ticketing, and a robust system in the parking toll collection system with an outlet at every booth.

**Note**: No citation, and I can't find any reference to it on the web.

**Question**: If these systems actually exist, what are their total lengthes (eg. 35 km total) and usage rate (eg. 7000 objects per day)?

References appreciated.

Comment: (asked after asking whether it is on-topic on meta: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3630/would-a-question-about-a-system-that-i-am-not-sure-actually-exists-be-on-topic)

Comment: There’s a bit of info here: http://www.expo1000.com/parking/press/20000322.htm mainly about the cash handling system for the toll booths, but it says all the systems were built by the same company.

Comment: Have you considered just asking Denver Airport on Twitter, or whatever their preferred social media platform is? There are a few web references from when the airport was about to open ([here](http://articles.latimes.com/1994-09-20/business/fi-40928_1_pneumatic-tube-systems), [here](https://www.wired.com/1994/05/tubes-2/)) but nothing recent, and [the provider's site](https://www.swisslog.com/) doesn't mention the airport at all. It looks like the system certainly *was* there, but I can't find any recent link that confirms it still *is* there.

Comment: @Pondlife we don't really want to send people away, do we?

Comment: @Federico No, but it's a good option if no one here can find a clear reference. And if the OP does ask them, he can always come back and answer his own question.

Comment: So we should ask on Twitter and then answer here? That's silly. :)

Comment: Not a pneumatic system, but "*The automated system was an underground, computer-driven railroad network for moving baggage. But bags were misdelivered, luggage was chewed up and cars derailed and jammed tracks. The system was responsible for repeated delays in the opening of DIA, which began operating in 1995*". There are some studies on this failure, e.g. [this one](https://www5.in.tum.de/~huckle/schloh_DIA.pdf) and [this one](http://ardent.mit.edu/airports/ASP_papers/Bag%20System%20at%20Denver.PDF). 27 km. (17 miles) and 4000 radio-controlled carts

Comment: I asked DIA by email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Public Relations Department at the Denver International Airport, as of May 24, 2019 there is no such pneumatic tube system at the airport.

> Hello Juan,
>
> Thank you for contacting Denver International Airport. We have
>   evaluated your email. I spoke with airport operations to find out if
>   they had any information on using a pneumatic tube system and they
>   advised me they do not. We do appreciate your feedback.
>
> Thank you, kindly, for bringing this matter to our attention.
>
> Warm Regards,
>
> Flydenver Team  Meseret

Comment: Would you mind posting their full email reply? Thanks!

Comment: That means they are part of the conspiracy!   :-)))